# ¿ Cómo crear TextView desplegables?

Tags: java, android, textview

Lo he visto en una `aplicación` y era lo que necesitaba pero no pensaba que existían. Hacías `click`en un `textView` (que al lado tenia una flechita de desplegable) y aparecia otro texto debajo y hacías `click` de nuevo a la **pregunta** y se escondía la **respuesta**. Y así tenía 5 o 6 preguntas con sus respectivas respuestas. ¿ Hay algún ejemplo tipo ?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que comentas, me parece que te refieres a un Spinner:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerQuestions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

El Spinner se alimenta de un array de elementos, al dar click, se expande y muestra todos los elementos.

```
String preguntas[] = {"Pregunta A","Pregunta B","Pregunta C","Pregunta D","Pregunta E"};
ArrayAdapter<String> questionsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, preguntas);
Spinner spinnerQuestions = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerQuestions);
spinnerQuestions.setAdapter(questionsAdapter);
```

---

Información de la documentación:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El Spinner casi que lo descarté lo primero, a ver si estás de acuerdo conmigo. Lo que yo quiero es una frase, algo elegante , una bajo de otra por ejemplo 5 textview y que al hacer click en uno de ellos se despliegue un texto bajo y después al hacer de nuevo click a la pregunta, se oculte. Si lo hago con el ``spinner`` no quedara mal? Las respuestas puede que sean largas y no sé si quedara bien y no quiero que pinchen en la respuesta tampoco.... No sé si me explico o si existe algo parecido.